# CSCART: How to create category programmatically

Tags: cs-cart

Can someone please help me to how to create a category programmatically in cs-cart?

I have tried to insert category details manually in database and it is displayed only in backend not in front end.

When i tried to edit it and save the category without giving any changes it shows the category in frontend...I dono what happen in that step.. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Check the tables you are updating (4):

```
*categories, *categories_descriptions, *product_sales and *product_categories,
```

I found the 'category_id' field in each one. May be it can help you. Or you can enable any MySQL logging system on saving in order to 'catch' any other tables involved in category info storing.